# is it possible to turn a HTML page to a PNG picture by just using Chrome's webkit?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, chromium-embedded

I am using Mac OSX and want to save some web pages as photos. I found that webkit2png is a nice tool but it seems it's relying on the webkit from Safari. But I just figure out that almost all the cases that I work with, Chrome renders better, particularly with shadow or stroke effects.

So I am wondering, is it possible to turn a HTML page into a picture by just using Chrome's rendering engine?

Thanks for any kind of tips,

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Chromium Embedded Framework. It can be integrated in C#, C++, Java, Python and various others. There are several examples of people using CEF to render html to textures (for 3D engines), so rendering to a png device should by all means be possible.